# Navbar collapse button not Displaying content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My `navbar` button does not work, i am working on this project using CodePen so bootstrap is already configured into the code.

```
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a  href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Nasr Almansoob </a>
  </div>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>     
        <li><a href="#"> About Me </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Aspirations </a> </li>   
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like its all working fine except the button lacks CSS if just using the default of the above code. Try styling the button so it's easily clickable using the following CSS as a start:  .navbar-toggle {background-color: #337ab7;}

Comment: THANK YOU! I added the jquery and forgot the bootstrap.js the first time, now i can see the content , literally owe you one , thank you Rachel~

Comment: @nasral00 I moved the comment to the answers section since that's what solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The order of how you link things makes a difference. In this case, you should add the jquery link first and THEN the bootstrap.js link afterwards. That fixed it for me [in this Codepen](http://codepen.codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/XdOygy).